# Base class virtual destructor - rule of five?

Tags: c++, state, move, virtual-destructor, rule-of-five

I have a base `State` interface class with virtual default destructor.

```
class State {
public:
    virtual void event() = 0;

    virtual ~State() = default; // relevant part

    virtual void onCreate() {}
    virtual void onDestroy() {}
    virtual void onActivate() {}
    virtual void onDeactivate() {}
};
```

And then some classes inheriting from it:

```
class GameState : public State {
public:
    void event() override;
    // ...
};

class MenuState : public State {
public:
    void event() override;
    // ...
};
```

Compiler generates default move operations if no copy operation or **destructor** is user-defined.
Compiler generates default copy operations if no move operation is user-defined.

1. Am I correct that by declaring virtual default destructor I have effectively deleted the default move operations?
2. Will the move operations work for the deriving classes if the base class had implicitly deleted its move operations, and the base class is just an interface without data members?
3. Is it really sensible to follow the Rule of 5 here? It seems quite a bloat to explicitly delete or default all 5 special member functions.

Comment: By the way, is there anything smelly about those empty-definitions methods in base `State` class? They are pass-through (state machine calls them anyway) and deriving classes can decide to override them or not.

Comment: yes on all 3. `State` is empty anyway, so both copy and move is a no-op. There is no ill effect.

Comment: @sp2danny - what do you mean by "effectively deleted"? They are not really deleted - usual copy operations are called when invoked with rvalue argument.

Comment: they are not defined. that means the overload resolution will find copy operations

Comment: It may be a good idea to explicitly default the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator because the implicit declaration of these constructor is deprecated: http://eel.is/c++draft/depr.impldec

Comment: You most often don't want any kind of copy or move in a class hierarchy, to avoid any unintended object slicing.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume your base class has copy (and possibly move) constructors and assignment operators. What would you expect in this case?

```cpp
MenuState menuState;
State state = menuState; // be aware that this State object is not a MenuState any more
```

In case your `State` class is abstract (if for example `onActivate()` was pure virtual) above wouldn't make any sense because a `State` instance would not be allowed.

But even if not, any `MenuState` members would be sliced, when you put them into a `State` object. If instances of your base class don't make much sense on their own, copy and move constructors and assignment operators should rather be deleted.

For derived (concrete) classes copying or moving might make more sense. In this case it can be useful to have `protected` copy constructors and assignment operators in the base class. So you cannot instantiate your base class itself, but your derived classes can make use of it.

```cpp
MenuState menuState;
MenuState copy = menuState; // might be useful
```

If on the other hand the base class makes sense on its own, `public` (and possibly `default`) copy and move constructors and assignment operators can be reasonable. This can be the case if derived classes just add some additional information, which is not required whenever you convert your derived objects to base objects.

So it really depends, and that's why it's better to explicitly point out what is intended, `public` copy and move, `protected` copy and move, or non at all.

Such class hierarchies, however, are often used with pointers (like `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`). Then a `virtual` `clone()` method sometimes is more useful.

```cpp
auto state = std::make_unique<MenuState>();
std::unique_ptr<State> copy = state->clone();
```

Internally this `clone()` method might use the copy constructor, though, which can be `public` (be careful of slicing, if your derived classes are not `final`) or `protected` (if you want to make sure only the `clone()` method is used).